# How to use iGraph for a given dataset and find all the graph properties

Tags: python, networking, graph, igraph

Given this dataset http://konect.uni-koblenz.de/networks/contiguous-usa I am supposed to find Centrality Measures like Degree Centrality, Stress Centrality, Betweenness and graph medians. So how can this problem be solved using iGraph. How to load the given dataset, I am new with this so can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Come on, there are a bunch of tutorials for igraph, including on the official website.

- [python-igraph Manual](https://igraph.org/python/doc/tutorial/tutorial.html)
- [Tutorial Igraph with Python](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/320386988_Tutorial_Igraph_with_Python)
- [A Walk on Python-igraph](http://eprints.rclis.org/29274/1/20153_figue.pdf)
- ...

I think a more appropriate approach is to first read a few of these tutorial and try to follow them, then use online documentation if you have some difficulties with certain things you want to do, and then only come to StackOverflow to ask *precise* questions on *specific* points.